# Syntax error near: When connecting to mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I've read on a lot of threads, but none of them is actually working, thats why I'm asking a new question.

Well, so I'm trying to insert values into my MySQL database but I'm getting the error.

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'Desc, Detectors, DetectorNos,
>   Question1, Question2, SpecialPrec, OfficerSign, Of' at line 1'

And I can't find where the problem is. I've been trying for hours without any result, even read all throught a hundred of times but still no luck. So I need someone else to take a look.

```
 public string detector = "";
    public string questions = "";
    public string question2 = "";
    public string capOrCheif = "";

    private void btn_send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(cbox_detectors_yes.Checked == true)
        {
            detector = "Yes";
        }
        if(cbox_yes1.Checked == true && cbox_yes3.Checked == true && cbox_yes4.Checked == true && cbox_yes5.Checked == true && cbox_yes6.Checked == true && cbox_yes7.Checked == true)
        {
            questions = "Yes";
        }
        if(cbox_yes2.Checked == true)
        {
            question2 = "Yes";
        }
        if(cbox_cheif.Checked == true)
        {
            capOrCheif = "Cheif Engineer";
        }
        else if(cbox_captain.Checked == true)
        {
            capOrCheif = "Captain";
        }
        else if(cbox_na2.Checked == true)
        {
            question2 = "N/A";
        }
        else if(cbox_detectors_na.Checked == true)
        {
            detector = "N/A";
        }

        string constring = "Server = **; Database = **; User Id = **; Password = ***; Sslmode = none;";
        string Query = "INSERT INTO tbl_permit (Username, Ship, Date, TimeFrom, TimeTo, Location, Desc, Detectors, DetectorNos, Question1, Question2, SpecialPrec, OfficerSign, OfficerName, OfficerPos, CheifSign, CheifName, CaptainSign, CaptainName, PrecAddedBy, PrecBox) values(@Username, @Ship, @Date, @TimeFrom, @TimeTo, @Location, @Desc, @Detectors, @DetectorNos, @Question1, @Question2, @SpecialPrec, @OfficerSign, @OfficerName, @OfficerPos, @CheifSign, @CheifName, @CaptainSign, @CaptainName, @PrecAddedBy, @PrecBox);";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(Query, con);

        cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add("@Username", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = login.username;
        cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add("@Ship", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtbox_ship.Text;
        cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add("@Date", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtbox_date.Text;
        cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add("@TimeFrom", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtbox_timeFrom.Text;
        cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add("@TimeTo", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtbox_timeTo.Text;
        cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add("@Location", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtbox_location;
        cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add("@Desc", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtbox_work_desc.Text;
        cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add("@Detectors", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = detector;
        cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add("@DetectorNos", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtbox_detector_desc.Text;
        cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add("@Question1", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = questions;
        cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add("@Question2", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = question2;
        cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add("@SpecialPrec", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtbox_precautions.Text;
        cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add("@OfficerSign", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtbox_officer_sign.Text;
        cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add("@OfficerName", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtbox_officer_name.Text;
        cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add("@OfficerPos", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtbox_officer_pos.Text;
        cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add("@CheifSign", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtbox_cheif_sign.Text;
        cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add("@CheifName", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtbox_cheif_name.Text;
        cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add("@CaptainSign", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtbox_captain_sign.Text;
        cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add("@CaptainName", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtbox_captain_name.Text;
        cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add("@PrecAddedBy", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = capOrCheif;
        cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add("@PrecBox", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtbox_restrictions.Text;

        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        if (cbox_read.Checked == true)
        {
            con.Open();
            myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Hot Work Permit Form has been sent to the Cheif Engineer");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have to read it through and accept it!");
        }

    }
```

Comment: `date` is a reserved word, escape with backticks.

Comment: @AlexK. How can I escape with backstick on that word? May you give me an example? :) Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: "For date you can put square brackets around the column [Date]." @user3352617 wrong, this is not SQL Server (MSSQL) but MySQL using brackets will syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DATE` is *not* a reserved word, despite the comment above. You can get a list of reserved words here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

That page lists keywords, but only a subset of those are reserved, indicated by the `(R)` annotation in the list.

The error message tells you which word caused the parser to become confused:

> ...check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Desc, Detectors, ...

It got confused on the word `DESC`. Syntax errors in MySQL always show you the portion of the query *starting* at the point where it got confused.

`DESC` is the reserved word causing a problem in this case. `DESC` has the `(R)` annotation in the keywords list I linked to.

You should delimit identifiers that conflict with reserved words:

```
string Query = "INSERT INTO tbl_permit (... Location, `Desc`, Detectors, ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I'm so stupid, ofc I can't name it Desc... I guess my brain were off duty. :s But that works perfectly fine! Thanks!